PLL error signal investigation using controller step responce
In general theory, when we design a controller we look at the step response and see how the controller is converging to the input .
However when we build a PLL system, our controller gets the error signal which is a phase difference of the input signal with the output signal, In my scope I see ripples surrounding some DC level as error signal.
Step response is not telling me how my controller will affect the PLL locking.
My PLL system only reduces the ripples but my DC level of error signal is not fixing at all.error signal need to go to some DC value and zero ripples.(I am half way)
I cant see how step response will help me forecast the error signal behavior.
When I design a new controller is there a way to see how the new controller will handle the error signal of the PLL?



Not sure I understand the issue- Are you saying that the steady-state error is not going to zero for a step input?  It looks like you have an integral term that should do that, is it not working?  When you say "ripples" do you mean ringing or instability?  That means you have to design the compensator for better phase margin.

Hello John,exactly I have build an integrator that should fix the problem.
Its AC and time domain  response is in the link.These responces doesnt tell me much, I need to know how good the DC part of the error signal will get fixed becuse of the new PI conteroller.Is there a way to see that?
https://i.sstatic.net/vlRYhso7.png
https://i.sstatic.net/oTVHmPZA.png
